# How can I re-run this jQuery code every second

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I re-run this jQuery code every second please?

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

I have done some research and it said I needed to put it into a `function` and set an `interval`, however I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Comment: You can learn about it at [MDN: `setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a little research and trying is required to ask a question here

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setInterval()` which takes function and the interval duration in milliseconds. In your case it should 1000 milliseconds which indicates 1 second.

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://example.com', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}, 1000);
```